# VBA script stops mid way, with no error as though it were complete

Tags: vba

I've encountered this in the past, when I'm doing something on the heavier side. This is confusing me though. I can step through it via f8 without issue, it runs fine with no errors.

The data macro just populates another sheet with external data. The code stops when populating the second sheet after it's pasted the data, but not the header. I noted below where the last execution line occurs.

```
Sub build()
o = ActiveWorkbook.Name
p = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Workbooks.Add
n = ActiveWorkbook.Name
While Sheets.Count < 4
Sheets.Add
Wend
Sheets(1).Select
Run "data"

Application.EnableEvents = False


o = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks.Add
n = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(o).Activate
Workbooks("Template.xlsm").Sheets(Array(2, 3, 4, 5)).Copy Before:=Workbooks(n).Sheets(1)
Sheets(1).Select
Range("A2").Select
While ActiveCell <> Empty

t = ActiveCell.Value

Sheets(2).Select
Cells.Find(what:=t).Select
If ActiveCell = t Then
Z = 0
While ActiveCell = t
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Z = Z + 1
Wend
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(-Z, 22)).Copy
Workbooks(n).Sheets(2).Activate
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A2") = t
Range("A1").Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
Workbooks(o).Activate
End If

Sheets(3).Select
Columns("A").Find(what:=t).Select
If ActiveCell = t Then
Z = 0
While ActiveCell = t
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Z = Z + 1
Wend
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(-Z, 5)).Copy
Workbooks(n).Sheets(3).Activate
Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  ***--This is the last event to occur***

Range("A2") = t  ***--This never happens, and the code never procedes***
Range("A1").Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
Workbooks(o).Activate
End If

Sheets(4).Select
Columns("A").Find(what:=t).Select
If ActiveCell = t Then
Z = 0
While ActiveCell = t
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Z = Z + 1
Wend
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(-Z, 19)).Copy
Workbooks(n).Sheets(4).Activate
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
MsgBox "hi"
Range("A2") = t
Range("A1").Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
Workbooks(o).Activate
End If
MsgBox t
Workbooks(n).SaveAs Filename:=p & "\..\workbooks2\" & t & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Workbooks(t & ".xlsm").Close
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not solve your problem, but for maintainers' sake get [Smart Indenter VBE add-in](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter) and indent your code!

Comment: Yeah, i have a terrible habit of just blowing through, then going back and indenting after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure that's what your problem is, but it looks like your code is working off implicit references to the `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` - avoid using `Select` and `Activate`, and work off object references instead.

It could very well be that one of the `Range` calls is being executed on another sheet than the one you're expecting.

The constant toggling of `Application.EnableEvents` is also a red flag: do you have worksheet-event handlers in any of the workbooks/worksheets involved? If not, there's no need to toggle it off. If so, then turn it off when you begin, and back on when you're done - but toggling it on/off/on/off all the time while `Select`ing and `Activate`ing things could cause some handler code to run and thwart your macro, depending on what application events you're handling.

Comment: I was only using activate/select because I'm in debug mode and wanted to see everything as I step through it.

I was disabling events because there's macro's that auto-run on the workbook that were throwing errors. It's an inherited project where hte data import broke, so I'm rewriting it.

I cleaned up the code and reverted everything, however still getting the same issue, it's still stopping in the sheet(3) function after the first pastespecial. I'm thinking there is bad code in the worksheet macro's, I just didn't want to open that can of worms if I didn't have to.

Comment: You can still debug and step through without select/activate. In fact, *not* using select/activate will make a more robust debugging experience, since manually inspecting the sheets while in break mode will not interfere with the execution.

Comment: rewrote it and it's still blowing up at the same spot, sheet(3) after the first paste. I'm afraid I have to go into the sheet macro's.

Comment: Looks like some nasty macro spaghetti you got here, my sympathies mate

Comment: It ended up being an error on a sheet macro onselectionchange(). I rewrotre the thing 5x before I found it.